# script to configure apn via sms

Tags: android, apn

I need a program that sends a script via SMS to configure the APN
I try thta program but not work on android, see online that this program needs to be saved in XML:

Can you help me combine this program and tell me how I should save it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.